# Спрятать уведомление после определенного кол-ва времени

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap

Есть уведомление через bootastrap.

```
<div class="alert alert-success" style="display: none;">Успешно</div>
```

Вызываю его так

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.alert-success').css('display','block');
        // $('#success').reveal({ 

         //})    
    }); 

</script>
```

Как спрятать его автоматически через 5 секунд?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/54ezdbeu/1/

Answer (score 1):

Можно реализовать так:

```html
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var alertSuccess = $('.alert-success');

    alertSuccess.css('display','block');
    setTimeout(function() {
      alertSuccess.hide();
    }, 5000);   

  }); 
</script>
```

Пример: https://jsfiddle.net/bo6dwpss/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bo6dwpss/1/ - в `jQuery` есть прослойка `delay`, с ней покомпактнее.

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь методом [setTimeout()](https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval)

С помощью него можно скрыть ваш блок через 5 секунд